# On GCP Compute Engine move_uploaded_file() is not working

Tags: php, google-compute-engine

I have a PHP application that allows users to upload pictures to the server, works perfectly fine on my shared hosting server.
I recently migrated to GCP Compute Engine using bitnami, this same code base doesn’t allow such uploads,
Does GCP not allow user file upload?
Is there any permission I need to grant to allow users to upload files to the server using the regular PHP function move_uploaded_file ()?

Comment: Are you asking us to research for you? If GCP allows SSH, use the CLI to set permissions. Otherwise, look at their documentation.

Comment: GCP does not prevent you from uploading files. Either your Linux file system permission or Apache/Nginx/PHP configuration files are not set correctly, or you have an issue/bug in your code. Yes, permissions can cause this problem, but your question has no details. 1) Show your code that is generating an error. 2) show the error. 3) show the request and file size details that cause the error.

Comment: @Jaquarh No, I am not asking you to do research for me. I thought it is a forum where people can ask a question to get there answer. I read the documentation when it didn't work I ask a question. But now the problem is solved.

Comment: @JohnHanley It was not giving an error it just skips the function but now it is working thanks for the reply.

Comment: Have you did anything to solve your issue? If yes, please post an answer to make your solution useful for other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier I have given the target URL as `https://<domain_name>/<folder_name>` to upload the attachment but it didn't work. So, I have tried to give a bitnami project URL `/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/<folder_name>` to upload an attachment and it works.

Comment: Thanks for sharing with us!